nuxtjs3 apollo plugin not receiving the pinia state on the first login
The problem is when I tried to click the login first I received null or undefined in my plugins/apollo.ts the userStore.authToken is null or undefined however on my 2nd time trying to login I pass the token in the header but it was the previous token not the current token of the user logged in.
**For example First time Log in: **
plugins/apollo.ts - userStore.authToken // result: null or undefined
console.log(userStore.authToken) // result: token1
token stored in cookie // result: token1
**For example Second time Log in: **
plugins/apollo.ts - userStore.authToken // result: token1
console.log(userStore.authToken) // result: token2
token stored in cookie // result: token2
const { onLogin } = useApollo()
const userStore = useUserStore()
This is my LoginForm component function
const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
        const variables = {
            input: {
                guard: "admin",
                name: username.value,
                password: password.value,
            },
        };

        const { mutate } = useMutation(query, { variables });

        const res = await mutate();

        // Login is equal to null/failed
        if (!res?.data.login) {
            alert("Incorrect Username/Password");
        }

        // Login is correct but account status is not equal to 1
        if (res?.data.login.status !== 1) {
            alert("Account Status is not equal to 1");
            clearForm();
        }

        // Login is successful
        if (res?.data.login && res?.data.login.status === 1) {
            // pass the token into the cookie
            onLogin(res?.data.login.token)
            // Store the token into the pinia store
            userStore.setToken(res?.data.login.token);
            console.log("Current Token: ", userStore.authToken);

            router.push('/')
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Something went wrong!");
    }
};

This is the store/user.js
export const useUserStore = defineStore("user", () => {
  const cookie = useCookie("apollo:default.token");

  const authToken = ref(cookie.value);

  const setToken = (tokenValue) => {
    authToken.value = tokenValue;
    console.log("Token Store: ", authToken.value);
  };

  return { authToken, setToken };
});


This is the plugins/apollo.ts from the nuxt-apollo documentation
import { useUserStore } from "~/store/user";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  const userStore = useUserStore();
  nuxtApp.hook("apollo:auth", ({ client, token }) => {
    if (userStore.authToken) {
      token.value = userStore.authToken;
    }
  });
});


I tried to async and await the functions or stored first in the cookie then get the cookie and store it in the token in the plugin
I also tried to add app:created hook in the plugin to ensure run only the plugin when app is mounted
Expecting answer: the token in the cookie and header should be the same.
